# How to specify default initialization conditionally based on templated member variable type

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a templated class that uses `std::conditional` to determine the type of a particular member variable. However, I'd like to also change the default initialisation behaviour (either in the ctor list initialisation, or in the member declaration itself) depending on that condition, as one of the options is a singleton.
e.g.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class NotSingleton{
public:
NotSingleton() = default;
};

class Singleton{
public:
static Singleton& getInstance(){
    static Singleton singleton;
    return singleton;
}
// delete copy ctor/assignment etc.
private:
Singleton() = default;
~Singleton() = default;
};

template<bool UseSingleton>
class MyClass{
public:
MyClass() {}

private:
std::conditional_t<UseSingleton, Singleton&, NotSingleton> m_member;
};
```

This does not compile when `UseSingleton = true` as `m_member` cannot use the default ctor for Singleton. How can I set m_member to initialise from `MultipleSubscriberListener::getInstance()` if `UseSingleton = true`?

Comment: Not an expert in C++. Instead of using `std::conditional` you could use template specialization here? `template<bool cond>struct myclass{\\ Non singleton; }; template<> struct myclass<true> { // with singleton; };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::conditional_t<UseSingleton, Singleton&, NotSingleton> m_member =
    []() -> decltype(m_member) {
        if constexpr (UseSingleton)
            return Singleton::getInstance();
        else
            return {};
    }();
```

If you don't want this to be a default initializer, you can also put it in the member initializer list of the constructor.

Instead of a lambda you can also use a member function if that looks cleaner to you. In either case the return type should be `decltype(m_member)`, so that the reference is passed on instead of decayed.

You could also use `decltype(auto)`, however with that there is potential for undefined behavior. If you use `decltype(auto)` and don't construct the `NotSingleton` object directly in the `return statement` (instead of passing it on from e.g. a local variable), then you would return a dangling reference, causing undefined behavior in the construction of the member.

Comment: @Joel Please note my edit. I made a potentially dangerous oversight in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In c++20 you could define 2 constructors and add the requirements:

```
MyClass() requires(UseSingleton)
: m_member(Singleton::getInstance())
{}

MyClass() requires(!UseSingleton)
{}
```